# Converting RTF to PDF in LibreOffice changes the margins

Tags: pdf, printing, conversion, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

When converting from RTF to PDF in LibreOffice, the bottom margin moves up about 3% of the page, leaving 3% more blank space at the bottom of the page. This causes some text to flow onto the next page, as it no longer fits.

How would I go about specifying the margins for the printing of the PDF file? Below is my code.

```
"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.bin" --convert-to pdf file.rtf
```

I played with some of the [parameters](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/pdf_params.html) but could not find anything useful. Is there a way to force the RTF footer to start at a certain spot in the PDF output?

[The RTF version (blurred)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4d9h.jpg)

[The PDF version (blurred)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TKqi.jpg)

Comment: When you played with params, did you set font embedding to true? Hard to tell, but the type looks differently sized in the two images. I think this would affect line height.